# Deployment of django using nginx

Tags: django, nginx

Im using django 1.11. 
i have set up everything on server and my website work just fine, the problem is static files. i see django admin panel without any `css` or `js`.

my settings in `settings.py` :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

i run `collectstatic` and i got them in `home/user/myproj/static`

here is my `nginx.conf` file :

```
server{
    listen 8000;
    server_name  my ip
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static {
        root home/user/myproj;
    }
}
```

i also check [django-static-file-and-nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144459/django-static-file-and-nginx) and [django-serving-static-files-through-nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451739/django-serving-static-files-through-nginx) , and tried 1000 times. it still loads without css.
can anybody help me ?

here is my full `nginx.conf` file :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name my ip
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    location /static/ {
            root /home/user/myproj/static;
    }
 }
 http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 }
```

Comment: What does the nginx access and error logs say, when you request a static file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your nginx.conf like below:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/user/myproj/static;
}
```

NginX will route client's request `/static/` to static files serving where is same as `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

> Note: url should be `/yoururl/` and location should be absolute like `/home/user/proj/static`

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar upload your full nginx.conf file to help you :)